# Exit thread within a nested function

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to check a global `bool` value in my thread whenever necessary:
If it's `true` the thread should exit, and the thread should continue if it's `false`.

While checking, I could be inside a single function or I could be within a nested function. I need to ensure that I return to the main function first, then `return 0` in the main function, which seems very stupid.

So the only way I can think of is to `throw` an exception when the condition is fulfilled and then catch it at the end of this thread, so that all the elements are destructed correctly.

So is there a more standard way in C++ language to do this? How do you exit a thread while you are in a nested function?

Comment: Exceptions are the standard way to perform non-local "goto"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Compared to the costs of thread creation and destruction, throwing an exception is negligible.

If for some reasons you aren't allowed to use exceptions:

- Check that signaling variable several places in your code. Note that regular code runs pretty damn fast so you only need these checks inside/before long calculations (loops) or IO operations that could block. Make sure the rest of the code doesn't depend on the results of some unfinished calculations.
- Use a coding style where you always return an error code from every function (at least for this thread).

Answer (score 1):

There are system-specific functions like `ExitThread` and `pthread_exit` but they are not recommended to use because they will result in memory leak: destructors will not be called, including CRT/stdlib internal objects if the thread was created using `std::thread`.

So the answer is: no, there is no standard way to exit a thread in C++. Just consider the thread as a regular function.